# Convert sRGB PDF to a different RGB color profile

Tags: pdf, colors, pdf-generation, ghostscript, srgb

I have a PDF with an sRGB color profile, and I would like to convert this to a different RGB color profile. So far I have tried to use ghostscript with various parameter values with no luck--for example I have attempted the following:

```
gs                                      \
-dSAFER                                 \
-dBATCH                                 \
-dNOPAUSE                               \
-dNOCACHE                               \
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite                       \
-sColorConversionStrategy=RGB           \
-dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB          \
-sOutputICCProfile=/colorprofiles/custom/AppleRGB.icc   \
-sOutputFile=output.pdf                     \
input.pdf
```

The command above runs without error but leaves the color space unaffected; the output.pdf still has the original sRGB color profile embedded.

Is such a conversion possible with ghostscript (or some other tool that can be used programmatically)? If so, where am I going wrong?

Comment: You haven't said which version of Ghostscript you are using. Setting ColorConversionStrategy to RGB isn't going to use a different profile, but it should turn all the colour specs into RGB, are you sure the profile is actually used ? Which profile are you checking, the OutputProfile ? Perhaps it would be better to put the original file somewhere public so it can be looked at.

Comment: @KenS Thanks for the reply. I have tried both ghostscript versions 9.10 and 9.16 (the latest version). An example pdf can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BybVwIX6T6OxbW91cmdQbDFWdWM/view?usp=sharing) and the AppleRGB.icc profile can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BybVwIX6T6OxTWpBNWE1LWlxWWs/view?usp=sharing). Also, I have been using `identify -verbose output.pdf` to verify the absence of the color profile.

Comment: When I run the file using the parameters you supply, I get a file which is totally in RGB, no surprise because that's what you asked for. The file I get has *no* ICC profile in it however.